# How to make rigged fingers follow a rotating crank handle's bone

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, constraints

So I have a simple musical box rigged and animated rotating its crank handle.

I have also a rigged hand posed to hold the crank handle of the box.

I want the rigged hand to follow the rotating crank handle so that it looks as if the hand is actually rotating the handle.

I tried probably all of the constraints but none of them seem to solve my problem.

I have also a control bone on the hand rig that I tried putting constraints with the bone3 of the musical box, such as copy location, tracked to, locked track and so on... But didn't work

Any suggestions ?

[image]

[image: I want my hand control bone to follow this bone]

Comment: have you tried to give a Child Of constraint to the hand bone with the crank as Target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way you could do is this:

Give all end finger bones an ik constraint with empties.

Move that empties to a position so that it looks good like the fingers grab the crank.

Add another (main) empty and parent these empties to the main empty.

Add a curve circle and move and scale it to the cranks movement.

Add a follow path constraint for the main empty to the curve circle.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't make it work. When I put IK on the end fingers and target an empty my whole arm gets distorted ? Also I already have another control bone on the wrist that is IK for the whole hand, is that the problem ?

Comment: on the IK constraint you have to restrict the chain length to the "right" length so that only these bones are affected which you want to

Comment: So I did something similar and I put IK on 4 of the fingers to an empty which is child constraint of the mesh object that rotates. But on the thumb finger for some reason the IK doesn't seem to work, the only finger which is just staying frozen not moving at all and I have no animations on it or something to make it stop it just doesn't work ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: if you can upload your blend file, i will have a look...it's hard to "theoretically" help you....

Comment: I cannot upload as the file size is 65mb and blend-exchange has a limit of 30mb. But very strangely while trying to move the armature and the objects only into a new file to make it smaller size, the problem got fixed... In the new blender file that I opened just now and placed the armature from my old file everything works fine all fingers are IK constraint to empty and they move as expected. However in my bigger blend file I still have the same issue where the thumb bone doesn't move at all even though it's IK constraint to a moveable empty...

Comment: you don't have to use blend-exchange...you could use any cloud-service you want....